# No matching sls found for 'state.sls' in env 'web'

Tags: saltstack

i am trying to execute a specific sls file on specific machine using

```
salt "remote-host" state.apply state.sls
```

but i am getting error which i dont understant why i am getting this error.

```
Data failed to compile:
```

---

```
No matching sls found for 'state.sls' in env 'web'
```

any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `.sls` from the command:

```
salt "remote-host" state.apply state
```